# ReferenceError: JST is not defined in Sails.js

Tags: sails.js

I have an ejs javascript template in:
`/assets/linker/template`

I changed the line in gruntfile.js from:
`linker/**/*.html` to `linker/**/*.ejs`

I have underscore.js in:
`assets/linker/js`

But when I try:
`JST['assets/linker/templates/addUser.ejs']( obj )` from `app.js`

I get this error in the console:
`ReferenceError: JST is not defined`

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a link to your github repo and I'll take a look.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I solved it by manually linking JST into my index.ejs file.
so I just added
  `<script type="text/javascript" src="/jst.js"></script>`
where I load my javascripts in sailsProject>views>home>index.ejs.
Not pretty, as the linker should do the job, but for now it works.
cheers

Answer (score 0):

### The Pipeline

The template files that are injected are specified in [tasks/pipeline.js](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/anatomy/tasks/pipeline-js)

The default is set to:

```
var templateFilesToInject = ['templates/**/*.html']
```

Files in [assets/templates](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/anatomy/assets/templates) (or any subdirectory) with the *.html* file extension are injected.

Also check out the JST task in [tasks/config/jst.js](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/anatomy/tasks/config/jst-js). It takes the template files to inject (from pipeline.js) and precompiles them into a file called `jst.js`.

Only once these other tasks have completed does the sails-linker begin its task. [tasks/config/sails-linker.js](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/anatomy/tasks/config/sails-linker-js) takes the `jst.js` that was generated by the JST task and includes it into the template start and template end tag in `.tmp/public/index.html`, `views/**/*.html`, and `views/**/*.ejs`.

So the default pipeline for client-side templates is:

1. Precompile `templates/**/*.html` into `jst.js`
2. Include `jst.js` in `index.html`, `views/**/*.html`, and `views/**/*.ejs` between `<!--TEMPLATES-->` and `<!--TEMPLATES END-->`

### Customization Examples

All of this default configuration can be changed to suit your needs. For example, to have templates with a different extension or multiple extensions edit the `templateFilesToInject` in `tasks/pipeline.js`:

```
let templateFilesToInject = [
    'vendor/templates/vendor_template.html',
    'templates/**/*.ejs',
    'templates/**/*.html'
]
```

Or to only inject templates on specific views if they have the comment `<!--TPL--><!--END TPL-->`, edit the `devTpl` config in `tasks/config/sails-linker.js`:

```
// Bring in JST template object
devTpl: {
  options: {
    startTag: '<!--TPL-->',
    endTag: '<!--END TPL-->',
    fileTmpl: '<script type="text/javascript" src="%s"></script>',
    appRoot: '.tmp/public'
  },
  files: {
    'views/that/use/templates/**/*.ejs': [
      '.tmp/public/jst.js'
    ]
  }
}
```